# A better way to space out navigation bar items

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to space these navigation bar items out evenly and there has to be a better way to do it then just giving all the li items a width and hoping they don't overflow.

HTML

```
 <header>
        <div id="page_wrapper">
        <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fun</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Utilities</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
header {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

nav {
    height: 48px;
}

nav ul {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
}

nav li a {
    font-family: cursive;
    color: #ff1e4b;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
    color: #dd5771;
}
```

JSFIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/rkmkxjm0/

Comment: Have you considered just giving them a percentage width and giving the parent a max-width of 100% (or just `width:100%`)? Or am i misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [flex](https://jsfiddle.net/rkmkxjm0/3/)?

Put `display: flex;` on your `<ul>`. Add `justify-content: space-between;` to it, and all children will automatically spread out to occupy the full width of their parent. Notice as you change the screen size, they adapt to fit.

(I've also set the width of your page to `width: 100%; max-width: 1024px;`, so that it will be `1024px` when it can be, but will just occupy 100% on smaller screens.)

If you want some space at the beginning and end, simply change `justify-content: space-between;` to `justify-content: space-around;`.

```css
#page_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

header {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

nav {
    height: 48px;
}

nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style-type: none;
}
nav li a {
    font-family: cursive;
    color: #ff1e4b;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}

nav li a:hover {
    color: #dd5771;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div id="page_wrapper">
  <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fun</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Utilities</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: That's quite good solution. The only drawback is that not all browser versions support it. However, I guess that's a limited amount of users so nothing much to worry about if that doesn't concern OP.

Comment: Correct, though it is supported by IE11 and up, so it's had full support since 2013. [Here's the MDN Compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Browser_compatibility), for reference.

Comment: Some 97% of the web supports flexbox at this point (with prefixes) – I'm generally unconcerned with recommending it. Reference: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there actually is. Instead of adding a fixed width, you can add a padding difference between each list item.

Here's an example of what you can do with CSS rules:

```
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

You can check the updated version of JS fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/NikolaosG/rkmkxjm0/1/

P.S. Your original jsfiddle has an issue with `<div id="page_wrapper">`. The div tag is not closed at the end (before `</header>`)

Comment: the padding doesn't space out the items evenly though

Comment: Depends on what you mean evenly. There is always a 10px padding around  each list item instead of fixed width. Otherwise he can use a framework like Bootstrap that can handle that kind of stuff for him.

Comment: sure, but I assume evenly means that each part will take an even portion of the parent div (amounting to 100% total)- that's up to the OP though, I might've misunderstood

Comment: Yes, that also is the definition of "even". However, if each part took an even proportion then he risks of having future list items being thrown out of proportions. Anyway, as you said, it's up to the OP. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care that much about backward compatibility, you should consider a flexbox layout, which is supported on most modern browsers, including Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Edge, and, to a limited extent, IE11.  (See [CanIUse.com/flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox).)

The layout with flexbox is dirt-simple; just delete the existing CSS rules for your `ul` and `li` and go with this:

```
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;    
}

nav li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

There are a whole variety of other layouts that you can do just as easily using flexbox; you can see all of the options here, with examples: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

If you can use external libraries- [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) has the [navbar-justified](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified) class which does just that for you